# Convolution with vectors

Tags: vectors, indefinite-integrals, convolution

I have what I suspect is a simple problem. Yet, I find myself stuck.

My equation describes the electric field at a point $\mathbf{r}$ due to cumulative polarization $\mathbf{P}(\mathbf{r^\prime})$ at points $\mathbf{r^\prime}$, and looks like this:

$$
\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r}) = \int \left\{\frac{3(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r^\prime})}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r^\prime}|^5}[\mathbf{P}(\mathbf{r^\prime})\cdot(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r^\prime})] - \frac{\mathbf{P}(\mathbf{r^\prime})}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r^\prime}|^3}\right\}d\mathbf{r^\prime}
$$

I want to eliminate the $\mathbf{r^\prime}$ by expressing $\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r})$ as a convolution of two functions of the vector $\mathbf{r}$.

Wikipedia tells me that the convolution is defined as:
$$
(f * g )(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\tau) g(t - \tau) \, d\tau  
$$
So it seems there should be a way to express my equation as a convolution with respect to $\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r^\prime}$. However, I'm not sure if this applies to vectors, or how to deal with the dot product in my equation above.

Any clues would be really appreciated!

Hugh

Answer (score 1):

We begin with splitting the integral into two terms:
$$
\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r}) 
= \int \left\{\frac{3(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r^\prime})}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r^\prime}|^5}[\mathbf{P}(\mathbf{r^\prime})\cdot(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r^\prime})] 
- \frac{\mathbf{P}(\mathbf{r^\prime})}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r^\prime}|^3}\right\}d\mathbf{r^\prime} \\
= \int \frac{3(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r^\prime})}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r^\prime}|^5}[\mathbf{P}(\mathbf{r^\prime})\cdot(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r^\prime})] d\mathbf{r^\prime}
- \int \frac{\mathbf{P}(\mathbf{r^\prime})}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r^\prime}|^3} d\mathbf{r^\prime}
$$

The second integral can easily be written as a convolution:
$$
\int \frac{\mathbf{P}(\mathbf{r^\prime})}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r^\prime}|^3} d\mathbf{r^\prime} 
= \mathbf{P}(\mathbf{r}) * \frac{1}{|\mathbf{r}|^3}
$$

The first integral is more difficult. The $i$<sup>th</sup> coordinate is somewhat easier:
$$
\left( \int \frac{3(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r^\prime})}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r^\prime}|^5}[\mathbf{P}(\mathbf{r^\prime})\cdot(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r^\prime})] d\mathbf{r^\prime} \right)_i
= \int \frac{3(x_i-x_i^\prime)}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r^\prime}|^5}[\mathbf{P}(\mathbf{r^\prime})\cdot(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r^\prime})] d\mathbf{r^\prime} \\
= \int \mathbf{P}(\mathbf{r^\prime})\cdot\frac{3(x_i-x_i^\prime)(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r^\prime})}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r^\prime}|^5} d\mathbf{r^\prime} 
= \mathbf{P}(\mathbf{r}) \stackrel{\cdot}{*} \frac{3 x_i \mathbf{r}}{|\mathbf{r}|^5}
$$
where the operator $\stackrel{\cdot}{*}$ denotes that both a convolution and a dot product are made:
$$
\mathbf{P}(\mathbf{r}) \stackrel{\cdot}{*} \frac{3 x_i \mathbf{r}}{|\mathbf{r}|^5}
= \sum_j P_j(\mathbf{r}) * \frac{3 x_i x_j}{|\mathbf{r}|^5}
$$

Thus,
$$
\int \frac{3(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r^\prime})}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r^\prime}|^5}[\mathbf{P}(\mathbf{r^\prime})\cdot(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r^\prime})] d\mathbf{r^\prime}
= \sum_i \left( \mathbf{P}(\mathbf{r}) \stackrel{\cdot}{*} \frac{3 x_i \mathbf{r}}{|\mathbf{r}|^5} \right) \mathbf{e}_i
= \sum_i \sum_j P_j(\mathbf{r}) * \frac{3 x_i x_j}{|\mathbf{r}|^5} \mathbf{e}_i
$$
so
$$
\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r}) 
= \sum_i \sum_j P_j(\mathbf{r}) * \frac{3 x_i x_j}{|\mathbf{r}|^5} \mathbf{e}_i
+ \mathbf{P}(\mathbf{r}) * \frac{1}{|\mathbf{r}|^3}
$$

---

Isn't the integrand the expansion of something? I think that I recognize it. The non-expanded expression might be easier to write as a pure convolution.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I suppose the integrand is an expansion, but I'm not sure of what - all they key textbooks give it in the form I did. 

Could you please ask you to clarify two things?

1. The steps involving $x_i$ and $x_i^\prime$, and a little more detail of the combined convolution and dot product.

2. The meaning of $\mathbf{e_i}$. Is it some unit vector?

Cheers,
Hugh

Comment: Yes, $\mathbf{e}_i$ is the unit vector in the $x_i$ direction.

Comment: For two vector valued functions $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$, the combined convolution and dot product is defined as
$$(\mathbf{u} \stackrel{\cdot}{*} \mathbf{v})(\mathbf{r}) = \int \mathbf{u}(\mathbf{r}') \cdot \mathbf{v}(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}') d\mathbf{r}'.$$

Comment: Could you be precise about what steps involving $x_i$ and $x_i'$ you don't understand?